# how can I remove all non-markup in html document with jsoup?

Tags: jakarta-ee, html-parsing, jsoup

I could see a lot of similar questions but not exactly. I just would like to remove all non-html-tag data (plain text) from a DOM using Jsoup. the result should be just markups without plain text.

Is it built-in with jsoup or should I write my own regExp ? Is it better to parse the entire DOM instead of RegExp and remove the contents inside the tags?

Which will b e more efficient, if I have to parse a lot documents/pages one by one, continuously?

**[SOLVED]**  -- see code below (for my req.)

```
public void getNodesHtml(Elements children, Element parent) throws Exception {
    for(Element e : children) {
        String nodeName = e.nodeName();
        String id = e.id().isEmpty() ? "" : e.id();
        parent.append("<" + nodeName + " id=\"" + id + "\"> </" + nodeName + ">");

        Elements subchildren = e.children();
        getNodesHtml(subchildren, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
removeText(Element node){

    List<TextNode> textNodes = node.textNodes();

    for(TextNode tn : textNode){
        tn.remove();
    }

    Elements children = node.children();
    for(Element e : Elements)
        removeText(e);
}
```